# Insert mailto:examples@org.com into HTML submit button

Tags: email, button, outlook

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitbtn" class="submitbtn" tabindex="7" value="Create Request">
```

**strong text**
I have this Button which is working fine but when it's pressed i want it to open outlook.
It it possible? it it necessary to use the same button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
<input type="button" name="submit" id="submitbtn" class="submitbtn" tabindex="7" value="Create Request" onclick="window.location.href='mailto:zveljkovic@hotmail.com'">
```